# While Loop being interrupted when if statement is false

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop

I have this piece of code that is meant to ask you what the blank word should be and then moves on to the next one if you correctly guess. That part is working fine, but if you enter the wrong answer it should ask the question again but is not doing that. Instead the python shell just sits there blank, no error, nothing. I can't see the problem:

```
while victory == False:
    if askq == answerx[counter]:
        newstring = newstring.replace(blank_list[counter],answerx[counter])
        counter += 1
        print newstring
        if counter < len(blank_list):
            askq = raw_input('What word is ' + blank_list[counter] + '? ')
    if newstring == answers:
        print 'Congratulations!'
        victory = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out! There may be a better way, but this just worked:

```
while victory == False:
    if askq == answerx[counter]:
        newstring = newstring.replace(blank_list[counter],answerx[counter])
        counter += 1
        print newstring
        if counter < len(blank_list):
            askq = raw_input('What word is ' + blank_list[counter] + '? ')
    else:
        print newstring
        askq = raw_input('What word is ' + blank_list[counter] + '? ')
    if newstring == answers:
        print 'Congratulations!'
        victory = True
```

Comment: The reason it worked is without the else clause, your program is stuck in an infinite loop once someone enters a wrong answer. Just walk through the steps "manually" to see what the computer is doing.